# How to show results of MyPy run in PyDev/Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, mypy

Cannot see results of MyPy runs in PyDev/Eclipse when selecting "Code analysis" on file or folder. Platform is Windows 10, PyDev (8.3.0) is running fine.

I made the settings but I can only see the command on the Eclipse console, but no further output. It can find the MyPy.exe of my environment.

[image: MyPy/PyDev settings]

Where are the results supposed to show up? The "Problems" tab only shows errors by the PyDev checker.

Running the command as shown in the Eclipse console in my WinPython environment gives the expected output.

EDIT: The link in the config tab to the documentation works now.

[image]

Another weird thing: Running "Code analysis" from Eclipse does not create `.mypy_cache`, but running the same command from console does.

EDIT2:

Note also the absence of any error message/result in the console window. This is Eclipse 4.19/OpenJDK 15.

[image]

Error log is quite unspecific.

[image]

The section "Troubleshooting" of the docu gave the hint: On a system with Eclipse 4.16/JDK 11 there was indeed an error message ("Unable to find MyPy").

Modified the way how MyPy is called and it works now.

[image]

Not sure if there is a better way how to configure a WinPython in the "Python Interpreters" section, so that it will find the stuff in the "Scripts" folder. Pointing to the "python.exe" is not enough.

Comment: I've just updated the missing link (https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_mypy.html), please take a look at that page to see if it helps you in troubleshooting (if it doesn't, please report back).

Comment: @FabioZadrozny Thanks for the updated docu, which allowed me to fix the problem. There might be an issue with Eclipse 4.19/JDK 15 so that "Unable to find MyPy" will not show up on console.

Comment: @fab Want to add yor answer so that I can accept/upvote?

Comment: Well, I've just pointed to the docs, you did the actual fix based on your config -- so, feel free to answer yourself or leave as it is ;)